# How to change the beamer font to Lucida Console?

Tags: beamer, fonts, lucida

I want to change my beamer's font to lucida console. I try but can not do it.

Comment: Do you have the Type1 or the OTF version of Lucida?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\usepackage[altbullet]{lucidabr}
```

or

```
\usepackage{lucidabr}
```